# How to Create JPath from a Type

Tags: c#, json.net

Whats the best way to create JPath from a given type.

Let's say I have below classes:

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}

class ClassB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want JPath for all props in `ClassA` e.g. `ClassA.ClassB.Name`

Is there a built-in method for this in Json.Net?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use SelectToken of JObject as follow:

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ClassA A = new ClassA()
                {
                    ClassB = new ClassB()
                    {
                        Name = "NameClassB"
                    }
                };

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A);
                var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

                var name = obj.SelectToken("$.ClassB.Name");

                System.Console.WriteLine(name); 
               // output --> NameClassB    

            }
        }

        class ClassA
        {
            public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
        }

        class ClassB
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Or using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

string name = stuff.Name;
string address = stuff.Address.City;
```

Comment: The Class will be genric so I can't hardcode the property name, I have build the property path first.